# Lua - round to double

Tags: lua, double, rounding, square-root

The result of `math.sqrt(2)` seems to be irrational so this occurs:

```
> return  math.sqrt(2)
1.4142135623731
> return  math.sqrt(2) == 1.4142135623731
false
```

How do I make this "irrational" variable same as if I got the variable different way (like in the example above)?

Comment: Lua cuts out last two digits intentionally to hide "irrationality" of simple numbers, such as `(1/3)*3` :)

Comment: Why do  you need the values to be exactly equal, with `==`? Maybe something easier (like represinting the numbers as strings with fixed precision or allowing a bit of error) will do what you need?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The variable is not irrational, it is floating-point, so it isn't even real. (the square-root of 2 is irrational though, and thus cannot be accurately represented by it)

Just use more digits for your literal, and the round-trip conversion will work. An IEEE double-precision floating-point value needs 17 significant decimal digits to safely represent it, not 14.

Let's see what happens when we take the number 1 and uptick it in the least significant bit. (The '0x' means the numeral is hexadecimal. That makes it easier for me to control the bits for this example.):

```
x = 0x1.0000000000001
> print(x == 1)
false
> print(('%.16g'):format(x))
1
> print(('%.17g'):format(x))
1.0000000000000002
```